# What is the meaning of Converted Leads

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

When i found job on job website, i found the term `Converted Leads` job(Related to marketing).

Please explain to me what it mean and what are the tasks will be done by this job?

Any information would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking "leads" -- potential customers -- and "converting" them into actual customers.